# How to create this Elasticsearch query body using elastic-builder?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'd like to create this exact JSON object using `elastic-builder` library

```
   {
        track_total_hits: true,
        query: {
            script_score: {
                query: {
                    bool: {
                        must: {
                            match_all: {}
                        }
                    }
                }, script: {
                    source: "...my script..."
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So that means `script_score` inside a `query`, then `query` again etc and if possible also how to add that `track_total_hits` key... I could not find a way to do that using their API.

There is a way using `functionScoreQuery()` to create a similar looking object, but it **was not accepted**. It was like below:

```
esb.functionScoreQuery()
        .query(esb.matchAllQuery())
        .function(esb.scriptScoreFunction(
        esb.script('source', "...my script...")
    ))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How you solve this, do you find some way :) ?

Comment: @SilvioHanky No, sorry. I ended up using another library for constructing the body called `bodybuilder`